Saving numpy array after indexing is much slower
I am running into an issue that saving a numpy array after indexing results in much slower saving. A minimal reproducible example can be seen below:
import time
import numpy as np

def mre(save_path):
    array = np.zeros((245, 233, 6))

    start = time.time()
    for i in range(1000):
        with open(save_path + '/array1_' + str(i), "wb") as file:
            np.save(file, array)
    end = time.time()
    print(f"No indexing: {end - start}s")

    array2 = array[:,:,[0,1,2,3,4,5]]
    start = time.time()
    for i in range(1000):
        with open(save_path + '/array2_' + str(i), "wb") as file:
            np.save(file, array2)
    end = time.time()
    print(f"With indexing: {end - start}s")
    print("Arrays are equal: ", np.array_equal(array, array2))

Which results in:
No indexing: 2.9975574016571045s
With indexing: 10.408239126205444s
Arrays are equal:  True

So according to numpy the arrays are equal, but still the resulting saving times are significantly slower. Does anyone have an idea as to why this is?

Deleted my answer since it won't help you get attention. Moving my comment from that here: I have seen some weird behaviour with slices before so perhaps there's something in it beyond the copy (which I originally thought caused this)

When you look at array2.strides compared to array.strides, you see that array2 is not in C order but that's the order that is required for saving. If you move the indexing out of the loop and write array2 = array[:,:,[0,1,2,3,4,5]].copy() to create an array in C order, the performance difference disappears.

I assume numpy changes the order so that extracting array2 from array does sequential writing. I think they take all entries for one index, then the next, etc. I will refrain from writing a full answer because I'm not sure about the exact behavior

You are right that resolves the issue. So the np.array_equal function does not take strides into account. That is good to know.

You should never benchmark arrays created with np.zeros. The array is not truely created in memory so it does not even have to be read from DRAM but 1 page in the L1 cache. The OS cheat by filling pages lazily. You should instead fill the array with random data. Writing non-zero data force pages to be mapped in DRAM (in usual configuration with medium-sized array). See: Why is np.zeros() faster than re-initializing an existing array in Numba with Python?

The base of array2 is not None.  The copy made by indexing has been reshaped.  Hence the change in strides. It's an undocumented feature of advanced indexing.

Have you tried to use the numpy.ascontiguousarray() function ?
This function is useful when working with arrays that have a non-contiguous memory layout, as it can improve performance by ensuring that the data is stored in contiguous memory locations.
Example
array2 = np.ascontiguousarray(array[:,:,[0,1,2,3,4,5]]) 

Output
No indexing: 6.80817985534668s
With indexing (contiguous copy): 6.550203800201416s


Thank you, this indeed solves the issue! Also good to know that whether an array is contiguous or not is not checked with the array_equal function.

You can try making array2 contiguous, you can call np.ascontiguousarray on it before saving:
array2 = np.ascontiguousarray(array[:,:,[0,1,2,3,4,5]])
It will create a contiguous copy of array2, making saving faster...
You should see a performance improvement in the saving time. cheers
